Is there a generalization of the Diameter Sphere Theorem to orbifolds?
The Diameter Sphere Theorem of Grove and Shiohama asserts that if $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature bounded from bellow by 1 and diameter greater than $\pi/2$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.
Perelman has a generalization of this result to Alexandrov spaces, which states that if $M$ is a complete $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space satisfying analogous bounds on curvature and diameter, then $M$ is homeomorphic to the suspension of a compact $(n-1)$-dimensional Alexandrov space.
It is known that Riemannian orbifolds are Alexandrov spaces. I'm wondering if there is a diameter sphere theorem for Riemannian orbifolds sharper than the direct application of Perelman's theorem, perhaps concluding that the orbifold is homeomorphic to the quotient of a sphere by some nice group action or a spherical suspension.
